# wp_query - show pages that have parent defined

Tags: wp-query, plugin-json-api

Can I achieve this with wp_query? I only want to get pages that have parent selected.

I'm using JSON API plugin and need to make a http request - would this be possible with url wp query also? For example, I'm doing requests like this: `http://example.com/api/get_posts/?post_type=page&posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand` and they work perfectly fine.

Perhaps using something like `post_parent__not_in => array()` (but in a url-like fashion?)

A better question could be: How to use WP Query arguments that accept arrays within url?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only child pages (pages that have parent selected), you can use this query:

```
http://example.com/api/get_posts/?post_type=page&posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand&post_parent__not_in[]=
```

And that should also give you the answer for your second question, I guess ;)

If you want to pass `array(1=>'foo', 2=>'bar')` as param called `my_array`, you should use this query:

```
...&my_array[1]=foo&my_array[2]=bar
```

Comment: The &post_parent__not_in[]= did it. Never used this syntax and queries inside url so was quite confusing I must say. Thank you :)